# ip route on interface based on the destination IP

Tags: ubuntu, routing

I'm on Kubuntu 13.04 with 2 interfaces eth0 and wlan0. 
I need to use the wlan0 only if the destination IP is *a.b.c.d*, and use eth0 for everything else. So I can ssh thay IP using wlan0 and not eth0.
How can I do it? Shoudt I use IP Route or there is a better way? Is that even possible? thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo route add -host a.b.c.d dev wlan0
sudo route add default dev eth0
```

Check before with `sudo route`because the 2nd line should already be present.